# How to set up different dpi-values for horizontal and vertical dimensions in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, dpi, imshow

I have a numpy array `arr` with the shape `(10,1800)` and I want to plot it as a 2D-plot using `imshow`-function in a Jupyter-notebook. By default, an image is plotted, but it looks like a narrow horizontal line, because there are only 10 rows. I would like to plot it so that the vertical axis would be stretched. The command below does not help, and I reckon it is because the dpi-value is applicable to both dimensions of a pixel. The question is if it is possible to setup two different dpi-values for a plot, and if it is then how to do so. Alternatively, if there is another plotting command that can do the job or another way to achieve the goal, I would also like to learn about it! Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 60), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.imshow(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imshow` by default sets the aspect ratio to "equal", and hence your axes will be condensed in the thinner direction.  To stop this, set the aspect to "auto", or set to some floating point number that looks good to you.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 60), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
arr = np.random.randn(500, 40)
plt.imshow(arr, aspect='auto')
```